# Elevation on Android 4 for non-CardView

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-cardview, android-elevation

I quite struggle with how to design the following picture in Android 4 and 5:

[image: dialog]

I have read (no reference sorry) that elevation is not implemented for Android 4 not even with appCompat library. I know that CardViews have the elevation even for Android 4. However, with CardViews I wouldn't be able to make that fancy arrow, would I? Do you have any idea how to do it? Please provide a code snippet to guide me through.

Comment: use that image as your background for your component. use 9-patch so it fits around your content.

Comment: wow, I have never used 9-patches. I give it a try. Thx.